# PowerShell: How can one define an alias with a fixed argument that one can extend with additional arguments?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to define me a PowerShell alias that presets specific Maven arguments and allows me to add arbitrary additional arguments. Concretely, for my build environment I need to specify a specific user settings file but I need to be able to add the goals and additional program arguments and/or options.
I need something like:

```
Set-Alias -Name mvn -Value 'mvn -s C:\Projects\my_special_settings.xml'
```

which I can later extend with additional arguments like:

```
mvn clean install -Pdevelopment -Darg=someValue
```

or

```
mvn clean install -Prelease -Darg=someOtherValue
```

which should be "expanded" to

```
mvn -s C:\Projects\my_special_settings.xml clean install -Pdevelopment -Darg=someValue
```

or

```
mvn -s C:\Projects\my_special_settings.xml clean install -Prelease -Darg=someOtherValue
```

, resp.

So far - whatever I tried - I keep getting

> mvn : The term 'mvn -s C:\Projects\my_special_settings.xml' is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
>   program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
>   verify that the path is correct and try again.

:-(

That can't be that hard - can it?

Comment: PowerShell aliases do not support arguments.  They are simply alternative names for an existing command.  What you need is a function.

Comment: Thanks. That's also what I have come up with by now. That plus some careful fiddling with single and doubly quoted strings depending on whether contained variables should be evaluated at definition vs. at execution times got me going. As powerful as PowerShell is, some of its design decisions and it implications are mindboggingly convoluted...
If you want your response flagged as answer, feel free to make it a response, then I'll mark this as solved.